# C++: Will any exception be missed by catch( ... )

Tags: c++, c++11

Does `catch(...)` catch all exceptions or will there be some exception that could be missed by this?

Comment: ["The catch-all clause `catch (...)` matches exceptions of any type."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch)

Answer (score 4):

It will catch all C++ exceptions. There are other kinds of events named "exceptions". E.g. Windows has "structured exceptions", which may or may not be caught by it. There are also unrelated "floating-point exceptions".

Answer (score 3):

`catch(...)` will catch any exception that can be thrown inside corresponding `try` block.

See the reference page (3): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch

Comment: @veda Note that "exception" is a very broad term here. I.e. this will also catch `throw 5;`.